# Table with cells left aligned and extra space on the right

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the cells of my table left aligned but at the same time autofit.

Example:

```css
thead td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
td {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<p>
First table
</p>
<br/>

<table style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Title 1</td>
    <td>Title 2</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td class="block">First column with some additional text (blah blah blah blah blah)</td>
    <td class="block">Second column</td>
    <td class="block">Third column</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br/>
<p>
Second table
</p>
<br/>


<table style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Title 1</td>
    <td>Title 2</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td class="block">First column</td>
    <td class="block">Second column</td>
    <td class="block">Third column</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

on the second table we clearly see that each cells are equal width.

**This is not what I wanted.**

I want to have each cells side by side without extra space between. 
Extra space should be on the right.

Edit: an image of what I want:

[image]

Comment: are you looking for cells without extra space?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo yes, extra space should be on the right side of the table as requested in my question.

Comment: just remove style=width:100%; form table tag

Comment: @AbdulMalik by removing the `style=width: 100%` my table is no more enlarged on the whole width. This is not what I want.

Comment: @Bronzato not able to understand. You want your table to be 100% but with out space???

Comment: can you please explain your question bit more. or an image of your desired result.

Comment: Let's take a look at this update: http://jsfiddle.net/wexdX/1992/ I removed the width 100% on the third table then you can see the table is no more expanding on the whold width but it should... So I want the third cells taking the rest of the space...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: if you don't want multilines in column use

```
white-space:nowrap; in `td` css
```

use `:nth-last-child` in your CSS to make it 100% in width

```css
thead td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
td {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
thead td:nth-last-child(1){
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Title 1</td>
    <td>Title 2</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td class="block">First column </td>
    <td class="block">Second column</td>
    <td class="block">Third column</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks Abdul.

Comment: you can you use white-space:nowrap; in td to avoid multi line text in column

Answer (score 2):

try it  help full

```css
thead td {
  background-color: yellow;

}
td {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
thead td:last-child{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<p>
First table
</p>
<br/>

<table style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Title 1</td>
    <td>Title 2</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td class="block">First column with some additional text (blah blah blah blah blah)</td>
    <td class="block">Second column</td>
    <td class="block">Third column</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br/>
<p>
Second table
</p>
<br/>


<table style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Title 1</td>
    <td>Title 2</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td class="block">First column</td>
    <td class="block">Second column</td>
    <td class="block">Third column</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i have add some css

```
thead td:last-child{
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 150px;">Title 1</td>
    <td style="width: 150px;">Title 2</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td class="block">First column</td>
    <td class="block">Second column</td>
    <td class="block">Third column</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't want to force `150px` on first cells. Please take a look of my edit with the image.

Comment: Is JavaScript a option?

Comment: No javascript please.